# How can I check for unused import in many Python files?

Tags: python

I remember when I was developing in C++ or Java, the compiler usually complains for unused methods, functions or imports.  In my Django project, I have a bunch of Python files which have gone through a number of iterations.  Some of those files have a few lines of import statement at the top of the page and some of those imports are not used anymore.  Is there a way to locate those unused imports besides eyeballing each one of them in each file?

All my imports are explicit, I don't usually write `from blah import *`

Comment: `for x in `ls *.py`; do echo $x; pylint $x | grep "Unused import"; done`

Answer (score 72, accepted):

[PyFlakes](https://launchpad.net/pyflakes) (similar to [Lint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lint_(software))) will give you this information.

```
pyflakes python_archive.py

Example output:
python_archive.py:1: 'python_archive2.SomeClass' imported but unused
```

Comment: will it automatically remove it?

Answer (score 18):

I use `flake8` to check the style, and then `isort`+`autoflake` to auto remove the unused imports.

Check: See more at [flake8 vs pyflake](https://www.slant.co/versus/12631/12632/%7Epyflakes_vs_flake8)

```
pip install flake8 --user
flake8 .
```

Reformat: see more at [why isort+autoflake](https://github.com/myint/autoflake/issues/8#issuecomment-430960914)

```
pip install isort autoflake --user
isort -sl .
autoflake --remove-all-unused-imports -i -r .
isort -m 3 .
```

Recently(since 2023), I use [ruff](https://github.com/charliermarsh/ruff) to replace `autoflake/flake8`

```bash
pip install --upgrade --user ruff
ruff --fix /path/to/file_or_folder
```

Answer (score 16):

Use a tool like [pylint](https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint) which will signal these code defects (among a lot of others).

Doing these kinds of 'pre-runtime' checks is hard in a language with dynamic typing, but pylint does a terrific job at catching these typos / leftovers from refactoring etc ...

Comment: You should note the exact command (e.g. `pylint * | grep "unused-import"`)

Answer (score 11):

You can also consider [vulture](https://github.com/jendrikseipp/vulture) as one of several options.

#### Installation

```sh
pip install vulture  # from PyPI
```

#### Usage

```sh
vulture myscript.py
```

For all python files under your project.

```sh
find . -name "*.py" | xargs vulture | grep "unused import"
```

#### Example

Applies to the code below.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2], 'B': [3, 4]})
```

The results are as follows.

```sh
➜ vulture myscript.py
myscript.py:1: unused import 'np' (90% confidence)
myscript.py:4: unused variable 'df' (60% confidence)
```

Answer (score 6):

Have a look at [PyChecker](http://pychecker.sourceforge.net/). It is a debugging tool and able to find unused variables and modules.

Answer (score 5):

I have been using [pyflakes](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyflakes) successfully and wished to auto-remove the unused imports.

I recently found [autoflake](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/autoflake/):

- Uses [pyflakes](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyflakes) for checking.
- Defaults to removing unused standard library imports and redundant `pass` statements.
- Has options for removing other unused imports and unused variables.

Comment: Autoflake fails for multiline imports

Answer (score 3):

If you use the [eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/) IDE with [pydev](http://pydev.org/) and [mylyn](http://www.eclipse.org/mylyn/), it provides automatic checking and highlighting for unused imports, among other things.  It integrates with pylint as well.

Answer (score 2):

[autoflake](https://pypi.org/project/autoflake/) is an improved version of [pyflakes](https://launchpad.net/pyflakes) with additional options.
It uses pyflakes under the hood, I would recommend to use it instead of using pyflakes directly.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with using [PyFlakes](https://github.com/PyCQA/pyflakes). It's like linting, but it excludes styling errors.

**UPDATE**

How to run: `pyflakes <your python file>` or `pyflakes <your folder containing python files>`

BE CAREFUL!!!

If you run it just with command `pyflakes`, it takes a really long time like it is never-ending. My hypothesis is it is trying to check every python file in your machine/folder when you call it that way.

Comment: Checking all files sounds strange. Does documentation say anything about it? Maybe it just waits for stdin input?

Answer (score 1):

[Importchecker](https://pypi.org/project/importchecker/) is a commandline utility to find unused imports in Python modules.

Comment: Seems to be unmaintained and does not work with relative imports https://github.com/zopefoundation/importchecker/issues/4

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following **user setting**:

```
"python.linting.pylintEnabled": true,
"python.linting.pylintArgs": [
    "--enable=W0614"
]
```

But I think, you'll need to go through all files yourself and hit "save".

Answer (score 0):

You can easily use **[pycln](https://hadialqattan.github.io/pycln)** to do that, just do:

```
pip3 install pycln
pycln path_of_your_file.py -a
```

And then all the unused imports are going to be removed!