# Checking if imported modules are ever used

Tags: perl

For whatever reason my coworkers (and probably myself in the past) have imported modules that we don't use to our projects.  It's so bad that modules that don't even exist are being imported.

In Perl, you can say something like:

```
use Socket;
gethostname("DERP");
```

It's very hard to tell from that function that it was tied to the socket module.

Is there any program that exists or some functionality of Perl that I'm not aware of that can tell you if you've got bloat imported into your script?

Comment: For Python, this is answered in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2540202/how-can-i-check-for-unused-import-in-many-python-files

Comment: Remove the import and run the test suite. You have one, right?

Comment: The answer to this question is very different in Perl and in Python – the two are completely separate languages. Please clarify which of these two languages you want an answer for, and [edit] the tags accordingly. If necessary, ask a second question for another language.

Comment: @amon done, that was very confusing.

Answer (score 4):

That's why I always explicitly lists imports. e.g. `use Socket qw( gethostname );` or `use Foo qw( );` (The latter imports nothing rather than defaults.)

One approach would be to go file by file and add these import lists, then stop loading module with an empty import list for which no mention of its package name exists in the file.

Answer (score 3):

Use a profiler to see what modules ARE in use. From that find out which are not. Works for me:

- Install the Devel::DProf module if you havent (`cpanm Devel::DProf` or if ubuntu: `apt install libdevel-dprof-perl`). Newer profilers also exists, i.e. `Devel::NYTProf`
- Change `#!/use/bin/perl` to `#!/use/bin/perl -d:DProf` in your program and then run it. This will make a `tmon.out` file in your current dir
- Run `dprofpp -aO9999` to analyze tmon.out. This outputs all executed subs including the module name on each line.

Note: if a sub is called conditionally (inside an `if`-block for instance) the profiler will not list it if the condition is always false. It helps to have a test suit with full code coverage and run that in profiling mode.

Comment: Changing the shebang is probably not a good idea (except when the program is not executed directly). Simply invoking `perl -d:DProf foo.pl` or setting the env var `PERL5OPT="$PERL5OPT -d:DProf"` are less intrusive solutions.

Comment: DProf is deprecated. Please use NYTProf!