# Is there a way to remove unused imports for Python in VS Code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I would really like to know if there is some Extension in Visual Studio Code or other means that could help identify and remove any unused imports.

I have quite a large number of imports like this and it's getting close to 40 lines. I know some of them aren't in use, the problem is removing them safely.

```
from django.core.mail import EmailMultiAlternatives, send_mail
from django.template.loader import render_to_string
from django.utils.html import strip_tags
from rest_framework import routers, serializers, viewsets, status
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
```

Comment: Enable unused-import for pylint

Comment: @HSK  elaborate on how you would enable unused-import for pylint in vs code

Comment: The far easiest way to do this: using PyCharm instead. :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Go to the ***User Settings*** json file and add the following:

```
"python.linting.pylintEnabled": true,
"python.linting.pylintArgs": [
    "--enable=W0614"
]
```

This should remove the unused python imports automatically.

More suggestions here:
[How can I check for unused import in many Python files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2540202/how-can-i-check-for-unused-import-in-many-python-files)

Comment: you can try using `--enable= W0611` instead. For a list of options you can refer to: https://docs.pylint.org/en/1.6.0/features.html

Comment: If you're curious where the User Settings are you can press `CMD/CTRL + SHIFT + P` and then type "settings.json" to bring it up.

Comment: Does it remove the code automatically? But it's not working for me.

Comment: Pylint doesn't edit your code.  This command will just highlight your unused imports.  (For me, it doesn't highlight the individual ones, just the line start, which is less than ideal)

Comment: @Dave: For me its the same. An import like from `django.utils import timezone` is not marked, only import like `import datetime`. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: @sinapan This doesn't remove any imports, or answer the OP's question.

Answer (score 23):

This is available now with a new release of the pylance extension (which I assume most people using python in VS Code will have).

It should be noted that the `optimizeImports` with the `ctrl + alt/option + o` keybinding only sorts and does not remove unused imports (see [github issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/17463)).

I have autosave in place, so I prefer a keyboard shortcut. If you have the pylance extension, you can add the following to your keybindings.json

```
    {
        "key": "shift+alt+r",
        "command": "editor.action.codeAction",
        "args": {
            "kind": "source.unusedImports",
        }
    }
```

You can change the key binding to be whatever you want, but basically when you press the keybinding (i.e `shift + option/alt + r`) it should remove all your unused imports.

I believe if you wanted this automatically on save as above you could add the following into your settings.json:

```
    "[python]": {
        "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
          "source.organizeImports": "explicit",
          "source.unusedImports": "explicit",
        }
    }
```

Comment: I could not get it to work with your command, but instead using `"command": "editor.action.fixAll"` (and no args).  One needs to  define also the settings `"python.analysis.fixAll" : ["source.unusedImports"]`. See also post below.

Comment: Have you got the latest update of Pylance? I note that there were a few versions ( v2023.5.20 < v < v2023.5.50) where this was broken, but the latest version has fixed (for me at least), see [github issue](https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/issues/4464). From memory the `fixAll` source action for unused imports was superseded by what I have written above, so maybe you have an older pylance version?

Comment: Adding the first block to keybindings.json works for me with Pylance v2023.12.1. (I have not tried the second block for autosave.)

Comment: Just a quick comment to say that VS Code/ python extension is under constant development. If something doesn't work for you, it might be due to an older version. You can check the edit history of this post to see some changes. Alternatively, in the `settings.json` it will sometimes give you grammar hints (w underlines etc) if something is incorrect for your version.

Answer (score 21):

Interestingly, the accepted answer does not address the question - how to **remove** unused imports.

Pylint does not modify code, it does linting.

Admittedly *i* still haven't found a great solution for python, but here's what I've seen:

#### 1.

As noted in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46722805/1177832), VSCode has a basic builtin option to auto-organise imports, didn't work that well for me - your mileage may vary:

<kbd>option</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> for Mac

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>

If this does the trick for you, you can also do it on save in VSCodes settings using:

```js
"editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
  "source.organizeImports": true
}
```

#### 2.

A module called [autoflake](https://pypi.org/project/autoflake/) can do this, e.g:

```sh
autoflake --in-place --remove-unused-variables example.py
```

But again, mileage may vary..

#### Note

I saw an [issue logged in the vscode github](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/109876) noting that the "quick fix" functionality is broken, and the vscode team indicated it was an issue with the vscode python plugin.. might be fixed soon..?

Answer (score 14):

- Confirm you have Pylance enabled in extensions. It comes with the vscode Python extension by Microsoft.
- In your .vscode/settings.json, add this

```js
    "python.analysis.fixAll" : ["source.unusedImports"]
```

Now when you do Ctrl+Shift+P (Comand Palette) -> "Fix All" this will clean up the unused imports.

- To auto cleanup on save, add this:

```js
    "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
        "source.unusedImports": true,
    }
```

you can also add "source.organizeImports": true in there to sort imports on save.

- If this doesnt work try overriding any other installed language servers with:

```js
    "python.languageServer": "Pylance",
```

Docs [here](https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/blob/main/README.md#source-code-actions)

Comment: `"source.unusedImports": true,` helped me to delete unused imports, thx

Comment: If one wants to run this action on a specific keyboard command, you need the         `"command": "editor.action.fixAll"` in addition to the settings above. Took me a moment to find it, and I think it is useful to mention here. (I would write the full entry from the `keybindings.json` in here, but comments do not allow multi-line code. I think it is easy to figure out after opening the file)

Answer (score 12):

The [autoflake vscode extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TrungNgo.autoflake) removes unused imports (rather than just highlighting them or sorting them).

#### What to do:

1. Install the [autoflake python package](https://pypi.org/project/autoflake/) e.g. via `pip install autoflake` (this will be used by the extension).
2. Install the [autoflake vscode extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TrungNgo.autoflake) via the extensions tab in vscode.
3. (*optional*: runs autoflake when you save) Install [Save and Run Ext](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=padjon.save-and-run-ext)  vscode extension and add these settings to `settings.json`:

```
{
    "saveAndRunExt": {
        "commands": [
            {
                "match": ".*\\.py",
                "isShellCommand": false,
                "cmd": "autoflake.removeUnused"
            },
        ]
    },
}
```

Comment: Thanks for showing me Save and Run. But once you've installed from PyPI you don't need the VSCode extension; you can just put `"cmd": "autoflake -i --remove-all-unused-imports --remove-unused-variables ${file}"` (or whatever options you want). Note the ability to [inline `# noqa`](https://github.com/myint/autoflake#excluding-specific-lines) to exclude specific import auto-removals.

Comment: @NathanielJones Thanks; nice point! One nice thing about that is that using autoflake directly gives extra flexibility on using the package. For those interested in using that method, note that it requires (1) changing the name of the setting to `"saveAndRun"` (vs `"saveAndRunExt"`), (2) dropping the `"isShellCommand"` option, and (3) using `"cmd"` to call autoflake. However, so far I actually prefer the `autoflake` extension because it doesn't pollute my terminal and terminal history with the command (when I used the `"saveAndRun"` as proposed, the commands were run in my active terminal).

Comment: That sounds nice to not have the terminal clutter. But where are you getting `"saveAndRunExt"`? In the link you share in your answer, the example shows just `"saveAndRun"`. When I add "Ext", my VSCode says, "Unknown Configuration Setting".

Comment: @NathanielJones Great catch! I actually had two separate extensions installed (the Ext version was a fork from the one I originally had which I had a link to).  I've now fixed my answer to use the extension I'm actually using which is now consistent with the setting snippet.  Thanks again! (and please do ask again if it doesn't work as advertised :)

Answer (score 10):

You can create such a [VSCode Task](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks) by yourself.

### 1. Install autoflake

```bash
pip install autoflake
```

### 2. Create Vscode Task

- Create ".vscode/tasks.json".
- Add the following settings.

#### Option 1. Without `activate`

```json
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "shell",
            "label": "autoflake.removeUnusedImports",
            "command": "${command:python.interpreterPath}",
            // in Git Bash, "'${command:python.interpreterPath}'",
            "args": [
                "-m"
                "autoflake",
                "--in-place",
                "--remove-all-unused-imports",
                "${file}", 
                // in Git Bash, "'${file}'",
                // to run on all files in the working directory, replace "${file}", with "--recursive", "."
            ],
            "presentation": {
                "echo": true,
                "reveal": "silent",
                "focus": false,
                "panel": "dedicated",
                "showReuseMessage": false,
                "clear": false,
                "close": true
            },
            "problemMatcher": []
        },
    ]
}
```

#### Option 2. With `activate`

The above method (running autoflake as a module) works at least on Windows (works in PowerShell and Command Prompt, Git Bash), and may work on other operating systems or environments. (I don't know because I don't have one. Please edit.) Alternatively, you can use `activate`.

##### PowerShell

```json
"command": "${command:python.interpreterPath}\\..\\activate.ps1\r\n",
"args": [
    "autoflake",
    "--in-place",
    "--remove-all-unused-imports",
    "${file}", 
],
```

##### Command Prompt

```json
"command": "${command:python.interpreterPath}\\..\\activate &&",
"args": [
    "autoflake",
    "--in-place",
    "--remove-all-unused-imports",
    "${file}", 
],
```

##### Bash

In Bash, it seems that file paths must be enclosed in quotation marks.

```json
"command": "source",
"args": [
    "\"${command:python.interpreterPath}\\..\\activate\"\r\n"
    "autoflake",
    "--in-place",
    "--remove-all-unused-imports",
    "\"${file}\"", 
],
```

### 3. Add the task to keyboard shortcuts (Optional)

- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> and select `Preferences: Open Keyboard Shortcuts (JSON)`.
- Add the following settings.

```json
[
    {
        "key": "Shift+Alt+P",//Set this value to any you like.
        "command": "workbench.action.tasks.runTask",
        "args": "autoflake.removeUnusedImports",
    }
]
```

In this way, pressing the shortcut key will automatically delete unused imports.

Unfortunately, [`vscode-autoflake`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TrungNgo.autoflake) did not work in to my environment for some reason.

Comment: Would be nice to have a cross-platform solution though unless Activate.ps1 (powershell is somewhat available in OSX and Linux)

Comment: It might work on linux and osx if you remove ".ps1". Also, although it is not generally true, but for autoflake, "${command:python.interpreterPath} -m autoflake..." seems to work fine even if you are using venv.

Answer (score 6):

I suggest to add `pycln` as a pre-commit hook, it desinged for this task!

(It works only with Python 3.6+).

Docs: https://hadialqattan.github.io/pycln

Repo: https://github.com/hadialqattan/pycln

PyPI: https://pypi.org/project/pycln/

Answer (score 6):

For now there is no clear way to do that on VSCode, but you can easily use **[pycln](https://hadialqattan.github.io/pycln)** to do that, just do:

```
pip3 install pycln
pycln path_of_your_file.py -a
```

And then all the unused imports are going to be removed!

Answer (score 1):

With this recently created VSCode extension, autoflake runs automatically by clicking on the context menu of the Explorer (in VSCode) tab or invoking a command from the command palette to remove unused imports.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mikoz.autoflake-extension

(As my previous answer was somehow deleted by a moderator, I'm posting a new one lol.)

Answer (score 0):

I recognize this is a workaround at best, but if you want this functionality, Pycharm and IntelliJ does it automatically with the optimize imports hotkey (<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>opt</kbd> + <kbd>o</kbd> on MacOS).