# How can I check for unused import in a python jupyterlab notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

suppose a jupyter file has several imports

```
import sys
import pandas as pd
import p1
import p2
```

however suppose p2 is never used and I want to remove it. The answer to the question for regular python scripts is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2540202/how-can-i-check-for-unused-import-in-many-python-files) and several others. But jupyter files are not regular files so cleaning them up this way might not work. I could not find on how to do this

Question: How can I check for unused import like the example above in a python jupyterlab notebook?

Comment: You might be looking for this library [nbQA](https://github.com/nbQA-dev/nbQA). I found it from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50358327/using-pylint-in-ipython-jupyter-notebook) post.

Comment: JupyterLab-lsp is another tool you can use